# Discrodjs typing for SubCommand Interaction

Tags: typescript, discord.js, typescript-typings

For a discord bot using nodejs, discord.js and writing in typescript I am looking for the correct Typing for SubCommand interaction? OR the correct way extend on the BaseCommandInteraction typing.

The scripts provided are just to generate the command on them self they are not working, as the project as a whole functions and the question is specifically about the typings I omitted the rest of the scripts.

If I set UnknownTypings to any the script is working so I know that the issue is with me failing to supply the correct typing.

To solve it I tried to google my issue and look in the typings index.d.ts but it became apparent that I do not possess the knowledge to word correctly what I am trying to ask.

Command.ts

```
import {
    BaseCommandInteraction,
    <UnknownTypings>,
    ChatInputApplicationCommandData,
    Client,
} from 'discord.js';

export interface ChatCommand extends ChatInputApplicationCommandData {
    run: (client: Client, interaction: BaseCommandInteraction) => void;
}

export interface ChatSubCommand extends ChatInputApplicationCommandData {
    run: (client: Client, interaction: <UnknownTypings>) => void;
}
```

The command with the issue of the unknown Interaction Typing

SubCommand.ts

```
import { <UnknownTypings>, Client } from 'discord.js';
import { ChatSubCommand } from '../Command';

export const Command: ChatSubCommand = {
    name: 'command',
    description: 'Some command',
    type: 'CHAT_INPUT',
    options:[
        {
            name: "subcommand1",
            type: "SUB_COMMAND",
            description: "desc here",
        },
        /*[...]*/
    ],
    run:  async (client: Client, interaction: <UnknownTypings> ) => {

        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'subcommand1') {
            const content = 'return content subcommand1';

            await interaction.followUp({
                ephemeral: true,
                content,
            });
        }
        /*[...]*/
    },
};
```

For reference a working command
HelloCommand.ts

```
import { BaseCommandInteraction, Client } from 'discord.js';
import { ChatCommand } from '../Command';

export const Hello: ChatCommand = {
    name: 'hello',
    description: 'Returns a greeting',
    type: 'CHAT_INPUT',
    run: async (client: Client, interaction: BaseCommandInteraction) => {
        
        const content = 'Hello there!';

        await interaction.followUp({
            ephemeral: true,
            content,
        });
    },
};
```